# How to prove : $\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty} x.f(x)dx$ is convergent

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to prove : If $\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty} x.f(x)dx$ is convergent then $\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty} .f(x)dx$ is too convergent.

Comment: How is $x^{-2}$ a counterexample?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty{x^{-1}}dx$ is not convergent.

Comment: Perhaps $f$ is supposed to be a polynomial?

Comment: $\,f(x)=x^{-2}\,$ isn't a counterexample since $$\int\limits_1^\infty \left(xf(x)=\frac1x\right)dx$$ isn't convergent...

Comment: Do you know Dirichlet's test or Abel's test?

Comment: @Landscape Nice! Dirichlet's test is the way to go.

Comment: @EricAuld: Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: Sure! I was going to ask you the same thing. I'll post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landscape made a great suggestion in the comments to use Dirichlet's test, so I thought I would write up the answer in this community wiki.

Dirichlet's test says that $\int_c^\infty \phi(x)\psi(x)$ converges if

1. $\phi(x) \to 0$
2. $\int_{c}^\infty |\phi'(x)|\,dx < \infty$, and
3. $\int_{c}^x \psi(t)\, dt$  is bounded as $x \to \infty$.

Here we can let $\psi(x) = xf(x)$ and $\phi(x) = 1/x$. Note that $$\int_{1}^\infty |\phi'(x)|\,dx =\int_{1}^\infty \frac1{x^2} \,dx < \infty.$$

*Note: to prove Dirichlet's test, just integrate by parts.*

Comment: Another version: replace condition 2 by that $\phi$ is monotone but not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: Dear Eric Auld, I don't think anyone should make an answer as community wiki just because I commented something before he/she post the answer. Anyway, (+1) for my appreciation of your work.

Comment: @FrankScience I didn't know that! Do you have a reference for a proof?

Comment: @EricAuld As far as I know, there're some Soviet textbooks containing it. The proof isn't hard, however, by the second mean value theorem for integration, and Cauchy's criterion.